# return items in array that meet critera

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Using the following code (or not), I am trying to return the `title` property of all items as long as the `title` property is not `NaN`

I understand that currently all items with a title property are being returned. How can I specify which to return?

```
function loadItems(id){
   itemPath = start.contains.models;
   for (var i = 0; i<itemPath.length; i++) {
      if(itemPath[i].attributes.id==id) {
         return itemPath[i].attributes.grades.models.map(function(g) {
            $('#foot').append(g.attributes.title);
         });
         }
      }
}
```

Comment: could you provide an example of what itemPath will look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outside the loop where you are just returning everything, define a container to hold valid items (empty array).  As you loop through each item, if it contains the title property and the title matches your conditions, add the current item into the container you made outside the loop.  Only add the item to the container you return if it matches your needs.

When you're all finished looping, return that container which should now hold ONLY items that contain the title and matching your check condition.

So like below, in your loop, if the title `isNaN()` add it into your array to return.

```
function loadItems(id){
  itemPath = start.contains.models;
  var returnMe = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i<itemPath.length; i++) {
    if(itemPath[i].attributes.id==id) {
      itemPath[i].attributes.grades.models.map(
        function(g) {
          if(isNaN(g.attributes.title)){
            returnMe.push(g.attributes.title);
          }}
      );
    }
  }
  return returnMe;
}
```

Comment: should be an array, not an object on your returnMe variable.

Comment: @captainrad updated the code to have `returnMe` be an Array now.

Comment: @captainrad Also curious if this block solved the actual problem or not (now using the array).  If it's not working, is there any feedback on what is going wrong still?

Comment: I actually was able to utilize some of your solution in essentially the same issue, this time however checking all items *before* pushing them into the array. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230423/push-objects-to-array-so-long-as-object-property-is-not-nan/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this??

```
function loadItems(id){
itemPath = start.contains.models;
for (var i = 0; i<itemPath.length; i++) {
  if(itemPath[i].attributes.id==id) {
     return itemPath[i].attributes.grades.models.map(function(g) {
      var_title = g.attributes.title;
      if(var_title=='My Title'){
        $('#foot').append(g.attributes.title);}
     });
     }
  }
}
```

Saludos ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?  I'm gonna need more info on itemPath to say for sure.

```
function loadItems(id){
    $(itemPath).find("#"+id+"[title]").each(function () {
        $("#foot").append($(this).attr("title"));
    });
}
```