# Push objects to array so long as object property is not NaN

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am aware that I could use .filter to achieve this, however I am not sure how to implement it.

I have objects as follows within an array

```
item {
  title : g.attributes.title,
  category : g.attributes.categoryid,
  possible: g.attributes.possible
}
```

however, some items in the array have a possible property of NaN.

**I need to make sure that only items whose possible property is not NaN, are pushed into the array.**

Here is an excerpt of my complete code:

```
function load(id){
   itemPath = lev1.lev2.lev3;
   items = [];
   for (var i = 0; i<itemPath.length; i++) {
      if(itemPath[i].attributes.id==id) {
         return itemPath[i].attributes.grades.models.map(function(g) {
            items.push(
               {
                  title : g.attributes.title,
                  category : g.attributes.categoryid,
                  possible: g.attributes.possible
               });
         });
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function load(id){
   itemPath = lev1.lev2.lev3;
   items = [];
   for (var i = 0; i<itemPath.length; i++) {
      if(itemPath[i].attributes.id==id) {
         return itemPath[i].attributes.grades.models.map(function(g) {
            if(g.attributes.possible !== g.attributes.possible){
               return;
            }


            items.push(
               {
                  title : g.attributes.title,
                  category : g.attributes.categoryid,
                  possible: g.attributes.possible
               });
         });
      }
   }
}
```

NaN is the only property in javascript that does not equal itself.  Just loop over the properties and check them for this, or use the built in NaN() function within the loop as suggested elsewhere.

#### Update

Since you're only worried about the possible property, just check that one as part of the if statement using `===` self, or isNaN()

Comment: I like this too... nice one.

Comment: It would be nice to see it build the object to push as it collects the properties that are valid. If hard-coded to 3 properties only maybe a more literal approach should be fine...

Comment: @kingdomcreation yeah I just added the note about that.  Its not clear if he wants to check all properties or just those 3.  If he only wants to check those 3 properties and ignore others he'll need to specify them.  If he wants them all, he'll need to loop like this.

Comment: I only need to check if the "possible" property is NaN. If it is it needs to be completely excluded from the array.

Still having a bit of trouble as all items whether their "possible" property is NaN or not are still being pushed to the array.

Any ideas?

Comment: ok then I recommend Bergi's solution so far.  Updating my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @captainrad ok I updated mine to reflect that you're only concerned about the possible property.

Comment: @ben336 oops, your update has a small problem as 'g' is not defined until the function is run.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your test line from

```
if(itemPath[i].attributes.id==id)
```

to use [`isNaN` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) on the properties you want to check

```
var attr = itemPath[i].attributes;
if (attr.id==id && !isNaN(attr.title) && !isNaN(attr.categoryid) && !isNaN(attr.possible))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `isNaN()` and test it before adding it...

```
function load(id){
   itemPath = lev1.lev2.lev3;
   items = [];
   for (var i = 0; i<itemPath.length; i++) {
      if(itemPath[i].attributes.id==id) {
         return itemPath[i].attributes.grades.models.map(function(g) {
            if( isNaN(g.attributes.title) || isNaN(g.attributes.categoryid) || isNaN(g.attributes.possible)  ){
            items.push(
               {
                  title : g.attributes.title,
                  category : g.attributes.categoryid,
                  possible: g.attributes.possible
               });
            }
         });
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're code is a little confusing

```
function load(id){
   itemPath = lev1.lev2.lev3;
   items = [];
   for (var i = 0; i<itemPath.length; i++) {
      if(itemPath[i].attributes.id==id) {
         return itemPath[i].attributes.grades.models.map(function(g) {
            items.push(
               {
                  title : g.attributes.title,
                  category : g.attributes.categoryid,
                  possible: g.attributes.possible
               });
         });
      }
   }
}
```

It doesn't look like you are using map right.  Map works like list compresions in the sense that it iterates over a sequence to preform some kind of operation on each element and returns a new sequence

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
var complexMagic = arr.map( function(n) { return n + 10; } );
// complexMagic === [11,12,13]
```

FYI, this is how filter, works.  Filter takes in a predicate function( aka, Boolean function) to build a new sequence.  If the predicate returns true, then the element will be stored in the new sequence.

```
var arr = [1, 123, 42, 1001, 1100];
var oddNumbers = arr.filter( function(n) {
    return 1 === (n & (-n) );
} );

// oddNumbers === [1, 123, 1001] );
// Bit hacks are fun ;P
```

It looks like you don't need items array or to even push new elements onto it.

```
function load(id){
   itemPath = lev1.lev2.lev3;
   items = [];
   for (var i = 0; i<itemPath.length; i++) {
      if(itemPath[i].attributes.id==id) {
         return itemPath[i].attributes.grades.models.map(function(g) {

            // You don't have to return anything.
            // This might be an ok place for the NaN check.

            return ({
                  title : g.attributes.title,
                  category : g.attributes.categoryid,
                  possible: g.attributes.possible
               });
         });
      }
   }
}
```

I'm lazy and didn't testing any of my code so reader beware.  Also avoid the push method if possible.  It can be a inefficient approach to append new elements onto an array.